# Spring jpa hibernate insert OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I'm trying to to insert data in table (OneToMany). I have two tables(Good, Category).

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "goods")
    public class Good implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @JsonBackReference
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    //getters,setters is ommited
```

And another:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "category_of_products")
    public class Category implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private List<Good> goods;

    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<Good> getGoods() {
        return goods;
    }
    //getter, setters ommited
```

Than, in category for example(id=1), i trying to create product which relate to this category.

```
@RequestMapping(value = CATEGORIES_ID_GOODS_ADD_DO, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addGoodAction(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                @Valid Good good, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
            goodValidator.validate(good, bindingResult);
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return JspNamesUtil.GOODS_BY_CATEGORY;
            } else {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                Category category = restTemplate.getForObject(
                        "http://localhost:8080/InternetShop/rest/category/" + id,
                        Category.class);            //here i have category by id

                // good.setCategory(category);
                // goodManager.saveOrUpdate(good);  doesn't insert anything

                category.getGoods().add(good);      //get all products from category and add new product
                model.addAttribute("good", good);
                categoryManager.saveOrUpdate(category); // doesn't insert anything
            }
            return JspNamesUtil.GOODS_BY_CATEGORY;
        }
```

and they don't insert anything in my table.

```
Hibernate: select category0_.id as id1_0_0_, category0_.name as name2_0_0_ from category_of_products category0_ where category0_.id=?
Hibernate: select goods0_.category_id as category7_0_0_, goods0_.id as id1_1_0_, goods0_.id as id1_1_1_, goods0_.category_id as category7_1_1_, goods0_.description as descript2_1_1_, goods0_.name as name3_1_1_, goods0_.price as price4_1_1_, goods0_.quantity as quantity5_1_1_, goods0_.short_description as short_de6_1_1_ from goods goods0_ where goods0_.category_id=?
```

method persist is also dont work(Detach entity exception)

example of DAO

```
public Category saveOrUpdate(Category category) {
        if (category != null) {
            em.merge(category);
        }
        return category;
        }
        public void add(Category category) {
           em.persist(category);
        }
```

give me please a hint, what i do wrong?

Comment: i already tried..
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [ua.internetshop.model.Good#1] are being merged. Detached: [ua.internetshop.model.Good@7842bec5]; Detached: [ua.internetshop.model.Good@1e897800]

Comment: Theres at least one failure. The em.merge operation returns a different object than passed as argument. So you should replace it with category = em.merge(category);. But I don't think that this will resolve your problem.

Comment: One addition, I hope it is clear to you that hibernate does not execute queries when you call merge. That does only update the internal representation which will get persisted to the database on commit. So are you 100% sure that you checked the log after a commit. And that a commit was executed at all.

Comment: the problem is: when category is empty, and i trying to add some product, everything is ok. But, when i have at least one product in caterory, and trying to add new one, hibernate did UPDATE previous product on new product, instead of insert new.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a test solution that can evolve depending on your tests:

There is two things to do:

1. Change your `CascadeType.PERSIST` to `CascadeType.CASCADE_ALL`To not have to deal with cascade problems (you can rollback this,  once this solution works).
2. Add an `addGood(Good good)` in `Category` class and add (if it does not already exists ) a setter for `Category` in `Good` class. You have to manage a bi-directionnal relationship wiring `Good` to `Category` and wiring back `Category` to `Good`.

The `addGood` method will be like this :

```
public void addGood(Good good) {
 this.goods.add(good);
 good.setCategory(this);
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but it still doesn't work.. When i debug i have proper objects in both sides see link below: http://gyazo.com/7e4f21cfc7f5f3e666db926bf44700e6

Comment: @oki  could you please make a screenshot like the one you did but i want to see the the java ids of the goods of the category. Expand goods elements inside in category and the new created Good id.

Comment: if i understood you correctly, you mean this: http://gyazo.com/d7e83e9613af3c97d7b13be0173c97cf

Comment: In fact in the debug panel in the right column value your have your objects and the JVM id like this Good (id=117). that's what i was meaning

Comment: Good but beside  that i need you to expand the elements of the list you have chosen ?